# Mockito gives error in put request

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am trying to make Mock Test of REST service that update data to database of given Id.

I have tried Add(POST request) that works fine.

But when I am trying PUT request it gives me an error :

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
service.updateMet(
    Met [id=10, name=mnTest, definition=mdTest]
);
-> at org.MetApp.MetTest.updateMet(MetTest.java:175)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
service.updateMet(
    Met [id=10, name=mnTest, definition=mdTest]
);
```

following is code :

```
@Test
public void updateMet() throws Exception {

    String cName = "mae";

    MetInDTO metDTO = new MetInDTO();
    metDTO.setName("mnTest");
    metDTO.setDescription("mdTest");

    DataTerm dTerm = new DataTerm(10, metDTO.getName(), metDTO.getDescription());
    Met met = new Met(dTerm);

    Mockito.doNothing().when(service).updateMet(met);

    mockMvc.perform(put("/restapi/{cname}/met/{id}", cName, met.getId())
            .contentType(contentType).content(convertObjectToByte(metDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(service, times(1)).updateMet(met);
}
```

**UPDATED :**

```
@Test
public void updateMet() throws Exception {

    String cName = "mae";

    MetInDTO metDTO = new MetInDTO();
    metDTO.setName("mnTest");
    metDTO.setDescription("mdTest");

    DataTerm dTerm = new DataTerm(10, metDTO.getName(), metDTO.getDescription());
    Met met = new Met(dTerm);

    final ArgumentCaptor<Met> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Met.class);

    Mockito.doNothing().when(service).updateMet(any(Met.class));

    mockMvc.perform(put("/restapi/{cname}/met/{id}", cName, met.getId())
            .contentType(contentType).content(convertObjectToByte(metDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(service).updateMet(captor.capture());

    Met captured = captor.getValue();

    assertEquals(met.getName(), captured.getName());
    assertEquals(met.getDefinition(), captured.getDefinition());
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you need to mock met object ?

Comment: I am new to it, so i dont have actually much idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot override the equals() method of your `Met` class, you have the option of capturing the output of the spied `service` and check that it matches what you want. You can do this:

```
doNothing().when(service).updateMet(any(Met.class));

final ArgumentCaptor<Met> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Met.class);

mockMvc.perform(bla, bla);

verify(service).updateMet(captor.capture());

final Met captured = captor.getValue();

// verify captured Met instance here
```

Note: for assertions you may want to use [assertj](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core).

Comment: Hi, I have added updated portion. Is it okay ? or still some problem ? It's running and test passes.

Comment: You miss the verification of the `Met` instance (see comment at end of code sample)

Comment: So how to do so now ? I have to assert ?

Comment: Well, yes, obviously. Verify that the name, description and whatever else are what you expect.

Comment: Also, your stub is incorrect. You should do nothing when the service updates `any(Met.class)`, not `captor.capture()`.

Comment: Sorry still not understand the last comment. at which line ?

Comment: Just look at your code vs mine. Look at how you stub your service vs how I did it.

Comment: Hey, I said **look at how you stub and how I did it**. I'll spell it for you: you `doNothing().when(service).update(captor.capture())`. Whereas I `doNothing().when(service).update(any(Met.class))`. As I said: your stub is incorrect.

Comment: Don't println() and just run the test. If what you say is really true the test should fail. OF course, you do realize that the capture won't be triggered until you call the MVC, right?

Comment: Excuse me, I have updated the question, look updated portion. That is running fine. Is it okay ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you override the `equals()` method for `Met`? The arg list is the same (in the first snippet), but it is saying you're using different arguments.

Comment: So where to override `equals()` method ?

Comment: Met class is packaged inside the jar file of another application. So i can't. Any other idea to do so ?

Comment: Can you extend `Met` and then implement the `equals()` method there? Even if the properties of Met are private you could use accessor methods to implement your equals method.

Comment: Hi, I have added updated portion. Is it okay ? or still some problem ? It's running and test passes